# How to debug openshift v2

Tags: python, django, apache, openshift

I am getting `Internal Server Error`

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at www.example.com Port 80
```

I have a django 1.8.8 on python 2.7 app. Looking at logs in `~/app-root/logs`, no info in cron_minutely.log or haproxy logs.  I also removed `.htaccess` from `app/wsgi/` folder. Lately I have set up env variables. (`rhc env set BLA=bla -a app`).

I have also read that env should be in quotes, so I tried `rhc env set BLA="bla" -a app`. No luck.

I probably should just get rid of openshift and move it to somewhere else. But it would take me too long to setup docker, vps for docker, postgres instance and crons on a small app. So please, do you have an idea how to find out where is the problem?

Comment: But what's in the apache error log?

Comment: I can not see any error log for Apache. Is it somewhere else from `~/app-root/logs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I've read [log files](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html) and noticed, I should restart app. `rhc stop app` and then `rhc start app`. And it worked. However I tried to restart in web admin interface, it did not help. This helped.

Comment: Sometimes a force stop and start is the only thing that works.  Restarts don't sways work depending on the problem.